# How can I receive a value of property from constructor object in sap ui5 js view

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, sapui5

I coded an object constructor in util.Common.js file which enable me to receive this object from everywhere. Here my object constructor taken from [javascript google maps examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates)

```
jQuery.sap.declare("util.Common");

util.Common = {
    /** @constructor */
    MercatorProjection : function() {
        this.TILE_SIZE = 256;
        this.pixelOrigin_ = new google.maps.Point(this.TILE_SIZE / 2,
          this.TILE_SIZE / 2);
        this.pixelsPerLonDegree_ = this.TILE_SIZE / 360;
        this.pixelsPerLonRadian_ = this.TILE_SIZE / (2 * Math.PI);
        Map.prototype.googlemap = null;

        this.createMap = function(mapOptions){
            Map.prototype.mapOptions = mapOptions;
            Map.prototype.googlemap = new google.maps.Map(Map.prototype.map_canvas_div.getDomRef(),  
            Map.prototype.mapOptions);
        };

        this.createInfoWindowContent = function(map) {
            var numTiles = 1 << map.getZoom();
            var projection = new MercatorProjection();
            var worldCoordinate = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(chicago);
            var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
              worldCoordinate.x * numTiles,
              worldCoordinate.y * numTiles);
            var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
              Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.x / TILE_SIZE),
              Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.y / TILE_SIZE));

            return [
            'Chicago, IL',
            'LatLng: ' + chicago.lat() + ' , ' + chicago.lng(),
            'World Coordinate: ' + worldCoordinate.x + ' , ' +
              worldCoordinate.y,
            'Pixel Coordinate: ' + Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.x) + ' , ' +
              Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.y),
            'Tile Coordinate: ' + tileCoordinate.x + ' , ' +
              tileCoordinate.y + ' at Zoom Level: ' + map.getZoom()
            ].join('<br>');
        };
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

and I'm trying to reach one of properties of object from home.js like that :

```
var me = new util.Common.MercatorProjection();
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 3,
   center: chicago
};
me.createMap(mapOptions);

var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
coordInfoWindow.setContent(me.createInfoWindowContent(me.googlemap));
coordInfoWindow.setPosition(me.chicago);
coordInfoWindow.open(me.googlemap);
var listener1 = new google.maps.event.addListener(me.googlemap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
coordInfoWindow.setContent(icm.Google.Charts.values.chart.createInfoWindowContent(me.googlemap));
coordInfoWindow.open(me.googlemap);
```

But when I write

> me.googlemap

it says googlemap is undefined and it couldn't create info window but I created it in createMap function so it shouldn't be undefined I think I just reached this value wrongly so I don't know how I can reach this value. Any suggestion would be very nice thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, you're defining `googlemap` as a property of `Map`:

```
Map.prototype.googlemap = null;
```

Yet, your object name is `MercatorProjection`:

```
MercatorProjection : function() {
...
```

I assume you want `googlemaps` to be a property of `MercatorProjection` (I'm not even sure what `Map` is?) - if you adjust your code accordingly (changing references to `Map` to references to `MercatorProjection`), your references to `me.googlemap` further on will work.

Unrelated to your question, but if you're working with Google Maps and UI5, take a look at [openui5-googlemaps](https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps).

Comment: At first I used MercatorProjection.prototype.googlemap but in this case it says MercatorProjection is not defined. I guess this was happening because I didn't declare MercatorProjection function like  'var MercatorProjection = function(){}'  I changed it as a Map and it works I don't know why but I thought Map is a general thing :D and thank you for link. This will help me a lot :)